# Added repo ol7_optional_latest and can't change status to enable

Tags: yum, repository, oracle-linux

Tried to add repo

```
[ol7_optional_latest]
name=Oracle Linux $releasever Optional Latest ($basearch)
baseurl=http://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/optional/latest/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
```

after execute

```
yum clean all
yum --enablerepo=ol7_optional_latest clean metadata
```

checked status repo and returned disabled

```
ol7_optional_latest/x86_64    Oracle Linux 7Server Optional Latest (x86_64)                                                         disabled
```

How to change status to ENABLED?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable a repo, do :

```
yum-config-manager --enable ol7_optional_latest
```

To **temporarily** enable a repo that's disabled you can use the `--enablerepo` option with `yum`, which is what you did. My answer above will permanently enable the repo and should change the status to enabled.